# matplotlib / scipy produces weird results when calculating and plotting multiple data sets (phase portraits of ODEs)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, scipy

Let me try to pose the problem I've encountered:
Given is an ordinary differential equation *dx/dt = f(x, t)* whose phase portrait is to be plotted by plotting the phase trajectories for an array of initial values with the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def phase_trajectories(func, inits, xbound, ybound):
    """func: RHS of ODE to be integrated by odeint
    inits: list or array of initial-value-tuples
    xbound, ybound: Boundaries for plotting
    """
    t = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)  # solution is calculated for these values
    axis = plt.gca()
    def f_neg(x, t):
        return -func(x, t)
    for i in inits:
        sol_fwd = odeint(func, i, t)   # calc solution forward
        sol_bwd = odeint(f_neg, i, t)  # and backward in time
        sol = np.vstack((np.flipud(sol_bwd), sol_fwd))  # put both together
        sol_x = sol[:,0]
        sol_y = sol[:,1]
        sol_x_masked = np.ma.masked_outside(sol_x, *xbound)  # masking the data because
        sol_y_masked = np.ma.masked_outside(sol_y, *ybound)  # of blow-up of the solution
        axis.plot(sol_x_masked, sol_y_masked, c='b')
    plt.plot()
```

As a specific example take a look at *dx/dt = x(t)²* with the initial value *x(t0) = x0*:

```
# inits contains tuples (t0, x0)
inits = np.array([(i, j) for i in range(-2, 3) for j in (-1, 1)])

def func(x, t):
    # receives x as array with shape (n,) from odeint
    # returns [dt/dt, dx/dt]
    return np.array([1, x[1]**2])
```

Now calling `phase_trajectories(func, inits, (-2, 2), (-2, 2))` plots the expected trajectories but also adds unwanted noise that seems to differ each time the function is invoked:
[example with noise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toK0H.png)
[another example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsSjS.png)

In order to get the bottom of this, I called `phase_trajectories` not for the whole inits-array at once but for each initial-value-pair seperatly using a generator with calling its `next` methode manually until exhaustion:

```
def generator_pt():
    for i in inits:
        yield phase_trajectories(func, (i,), (-2, 2), (-2, 2))

g = generator_pt()
next(g)
```

This, however, would sometimes (strangely not every time) give me the desired result:
[It's supposed to look like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCGxb.png)

I know that the solution of the given ODE blows up, meaning it exists only on a specific intervall and diverges when approaching its limits, which is why I masked the arrays holding the data befor plotting.
It remains enigmatic to me nonetheless, why the unwanted noise differs each time the data is calculated and plotted.

Based on the here stated observations, I believe the cause of this misbehaviour is to be sought within matplotlib or rather in some horrible misuse of this library on my side.
I already tried using different matplotlib-backends and executing the code in different environments (Python 2.7 and 3.5) with the necessary packeges updated, but my struggel remaind without fruit so far and I'm getting to a point where I merely grasp at straws.

Perhaps someone could give me a hint or provide some insight which would explain these results or at least help me understand why things are happening this way.

*Stackoverflow, You are my only hope...*

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem lies within scipys `odeint` methode, which is an older implementation to numerically solve ODEs. Since scipy v1.0.0 a new implementation with `solve_ivp` is available with which the disturbing noise doesn't appear.
For reference:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

def phase_trajectories(func, inits, xbound, ybound):
    axis = plt.gca()
    t = (0, 10)
    def f_neg(t, x):
        return -func(t, x)
    for f in (func, f_neg):
        for i in inits:
            x, y = solve_ivp(f, t, i).y
            x_ma = np.ma.masked_outside(x, *xbound)
            y_ma = np.ma.masked_outside(y, *ybound)
            axis.plot(x_ma, y_ma, c='b')
    plt.plot()
```

The result for the function and the initial values [looks as aspected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDHi3.png).

The reason, however, why `odeint` is showing its strange behaviour remains as of yet unanswered to me and is propably to be found in the underlying FORTRAN-implementation.